# Book recommendations (for free) about basic hypergeometric series (q-hypergeometric series)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, book-recommendation

I am presently dealing with Rogers-Ramanujan-identities and need to teach myself the basics about q- hypergeometrical series and need a book or paper for free. Do you know any and could recommend them ?

Comment: Maybe just check out your universities library?

Comment: Also you get almost every book via libgen.is